# Can SignalR be used with website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, owin

I am working on a legacy ASP.NET web site (not a web application) and I need to add SignalR functionality. SignalR now relies on OWIN. Is it possible to use the latest version of SignalR, if so how? I can install it all fine from nuget to the website project but cannot get the OWIN startup class to be recognised. I am considering using an older version of SignalR that doesn't rely on OWIN.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Comment: thanks Mark - I can't see that the linked page tells me what I need to know though :)

Comment: SignalR 2 is only supported on ASP.NET 4.5  I'm assuming that your legacy web site probably is not running on 4.5  As a result, you couldn't use the latest version of SignalR even if you moved away from OWIN

Comment: @DavidL, but the client side using javascript should be independent of the .net version, no?

Comment: @AD.Net Not necessarily. The client-side javascript that operates as hub proxies is generated serverside. So to say that the javascript is .net framework version agnostic is incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried using SignalR in a website project? Seems like it'd be a trivial thing to test.

Comment: @DavidL True, but those proxies can be generated by one version of .NET and then saved, then you can choose to reference those instead of the default ~/signalr proxies generated at runtime. Microsoft employees have demonstrated this at least once.

Comment: @mason true, but that's highly outside the scope of the OP's question.